# How to write progress bar in javascript for Phonegap application

Tags: javascript, cordova, progress-bar

I am developing a Phonegap application for Android.In a part of my code (in javascript),Images loading from server.When loading an image I want to show a progress bar that will show how many percentage of the image is loading .How can i write it in javascript?
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way is to count the number of pictures that are being moved and increment the progressbar 1/(#ofFiles) each time. The problem with this is that if some files are much larger than others, it will not be accurate.

The better solution would be to use the actual filesize, and the filesize of all the files moving, so if there is a 5 files, and one of them is very large comparatively, then it will properly increment more once that file has completed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mac.I have already code that get the images from server , but how can i write the code after each coming image?Do i need to jquery?